# ApplicationInfo LoadLabel increase memory consumption of my service (android)

Tags: android, memory-management

I wrote a android service which computes list of applications installed on the phone and get the application names.

Code roughly looks like this:

```
List<PackageInfo> appListInfo = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
                for (PackageInfo p : appListInfo) { p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());                                           }
```

What i have observed is, the `loadLabel` function when called on all the `packageInfo` objects increases the memory consumption a lot. My service takes 3-5 mb usually and spikes to 16mb when this code is executed.

Though, this memory gets released eventually (when GC runs) and service goes back to 3-5mb, I want to know if this spike can be avoided and still achieve my goals

Reason I want this is, I am planning to market this app as light-weight, which is not possible if this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory consumption should not concern you here since big spike does not automatically mean that the memory could not be reclaimed at that time. It may just mean that garbage collection was not necessary since there was enough free memory. Using more memory can even make things faster and using free memory has no negative side-effects.

But you could try the following to make sure that objects can get GC'd earlier:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (int i = 0; i < packages.size(); i++) {
    PackageInfo p = packages.set(i, null);
    p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
}
packages = null;
```

That could help in case the `PackageInfo` objects retain extra memory once you call the `loadLabel` method. With above approach the reference to those is cleared after the info was loaded while in your approach they all remain referenced by the list and can only be GC'd once the whole loop is finished and `packages` can be GC'd.

> I am planning to market this app as light-weight, which is not possible if this keeps happening.

I doubt that users will monitor the memory usage for spikes. Also the typical perception of memory is kind of wrong. Free memory = wasted resources, not speeding up your phone if you have it. Marketing != technical details :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. My app, which normally uses 32mb spikes to 50mb. The loadLabel is being called in a runnable that gets called every x seconds/minutes from the service. I've seen the memory go as high as 90mb. I trust the GC but my app records data and needs to be running all the time so it's very eligible for termination from the OS.

My solution has been to null the ApplicationInfo then call System.gc() to free the memory. This way my app stays at 32mb.

If anyone has a better way please inform us.

Answer (score 2):

Its never too late to reply

What is happening behind the scenes is android loads every application apk and hence it's resource in order to get the text from the resource.

Though the resources won't get closed until GC happens, there is away around it, with some cost and only when you are worried about increasing size.

You can use hidden APIs and load the resources yourself and remove them once done.

```
...
Resources res;
AssetManager assetMgr;  
DisplayMetrics metrics = getDisplayMetricsLocked(null, false);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
int tmpResId;
for (PackageInfo p: packages){
     tmpResId = p.applicationInfo.labelRes;
     if(tmpResId == 0){
         p.applicationInfo.setAppName(p.applicationInfo.nonLocalizedLabel);
     }else {
        //hidden API's here
        assetMgr = new AssetManager();
        if(assetMgr.addAssetPath(p.applicationInfo.sourceDir) == 0){
        if(assetMgr.addAssetPath(p.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir) == 0){
           continue;
        }
        }
        res = new Resources(assetMgr, metrics, config);
        //Get your label here
        ...res.getText(tmpResId);
        res.getAssets().close();
    }

}
assetMgr = null;
res = null;
...

static DisplayMetrics getDisplayMetricsLocked(CompatibilityInfo ci, boolean  forceUpdate) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    Display d = WindowManagerImpl.getDefault(ci).getDefaultDisplay();
    d.getMetrics(dm);
    return dm;
}
```